# Optimization of my soundboard code

Tags: android, optimization

I think the best is to first say, that I recently started Android programming. Despite the fact of me getting better now, I can't seem to find good ways to optimize my piece of code.

I've written this piece of code. It's a soundboard. And when you long click a button you're able to save it as a ringtone, as a alarm, as a notification or share it with your friends. For every method I've made a string.

This string is set by the corresponding button to "btn1" till "btn20". After this I open the method (in the example below `showSelectedSaveDialog()`. And in that method I've made a if or if else statement to open the correct sound.

This way of coding makes a very long code. Because for every button I have to make an `if else` statement. Is there a better way to code kind codes? Is there a good tutorial, or something like that? Or someone who can post an example?

`Setting the string:`

```
ringToneManager = "btn1";
showSelectSaveDialog();
```

`Setting the correct sound:`

```
if (str.equals("btn1")) {
    fIn = getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext().getResources()
        .openRawResource(R.raw.sound01);
```

`Starting the method to share the sound file`

```
shareButton("btn14");
```

`Getting the corresponding sound file`

```
private void shareButton(String str) {
    // SAVE THE FILE
    byte[] buffer = null;

    if (str.equals("btn1")) {
        fIn = getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext().getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.sound01);
[...] etc
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using the "tag" property, available on all Views and widgets. The tag property is a general purpose container.

Load the tag property for each button with the id of the sound file associated with the button, this can be done on an activities onCreate:

```
findViewById(R.id.btn1).setTag(R.raw.sound01);
findViewById(R.id.btn2).setTag(R.raw.sound02);
//etc.
findViewById(R.id.btn20).setTag(R.raw.sound20);
```

Each button can now share the same onClick handler and all run the same piece of code, no ifs required:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    fIn = getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource((Integer)arg0.getTag());
}
```

Likewise change the shareButton method to take an integer instead of a string:

```
shareButton((Integer)arg0.getTag());

private void shareButton(int soundID) {
    // SAVE THE FILE
    byte[] buffer = null;

    fIn = getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(soundID);
[...] etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me really much! Will try to change my code now! :)

Comment: I've made a few methods in my activity. Some of those methods are started in my Context Menu. for example to use `setRingtone();` I have to pas a View in the method. What do I put there